# JSON contact list to be called from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, list, contacts

I have a list of users in my database (users), what I want to do is organize them from A-Z and 0-9.

I then would like jQuery to take that JSON and use it to show a list like this:

```
A
Alex
Andrew
Ann

B
Ben
Benny
Buck

C
Colin
Col

etc
```

But I am not sure how to do it. I have the JSON but not the jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the json is already an array you don't need to do anything other than:

```
$.get('/path', function (data) {
  console.log('data'); //Should already be an array.
});
```

Arrays are a supported datatype in json.

If your array is not sorted yet take a look at [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {//your js code to use data});` this is particularly if your dataType is always json, or else `$.get('ajax/test.json', function(data) {//your js code to use data});`

This two methods are shorthand methods for jquery ajax method

```
$.ajax({
  url: serverUrl,
  data: 'data you need to pass to server(query params)',
  success: success function,
  dataType: dataType of data returned by server (json, xml, html)
});
```